# Calling model function in view codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC, I am porting a project written in non-MVC style to MVC, but I am stuck on a problem where it is necessary to call Model function in View.

#### Scenario:

Table1 - **Products:**
contains `product_id`, `product_name` etc. and for each product there can be multiple versions.

Table2 - **Versions:**
contains `version_id`, `version_name`, ... , `product_id` etc.

Now in the View I am displaying products and under each product heading I have to display version list of that product, in non-MVC style it was pretty simple, I can use the following code snippet in View:

```php
foreach ($product as $row) 
{
    echo $row['product_name'];
    if ($main->getVersionList($vresult,$row["product_id"]))
    {
        foreach ($vresult as $vrow)
        {
          echo $vrow['version_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can pass Product array from controller to view but what about each *Version* array which needs to be generated corresponding to each product?

**Update:**

This is my final working solution (used a map), in controller:

```
        $this->load->model ( 'product_mod' );
        $data ['products'] = $this->product_mod->getProductList ();
        $data ['versions'] = array ();
        foreach ( $data ['products'] as $product )
        {
            $data ['versions'] [$product['product_id']] =   $this->product_mod->getVersionList ( $product['product_id'] );
        }
```

Comment: Just updated the answer to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution -- arrays can be so confusing to figure out -- its funny how simple it usually is to implement :-)

Comment: @cartalot Runnig SQL queries within loops causes overhead and doesn't make any sense while you're using **[RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)**. You could `JOIN` the tables to fetch the related data, as I suggested in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662859/calling-model-function-in-view-codeigniter/21663343#21663343).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### MVC or not to MVC

The first thing I should note is that **[*It is impossible to write classical MVC in PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621832/architecture-more-suitable-for-web-apps-than-mvc/7622038#7622038)**. In fact the MVC-like PHP frameworks such as CodeIgniter or Yii implements [sort of **MVP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900627/simple-mvp-example-with-php/10960780#10960780) in which:

- view is passive and unaware of model
- presenter (controller) changes state of model, reads information and passes it to view

*Credits to [tereško](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/teresko)*

### CodeIgniter Approach

However, particularly in CodeIgniter, you have 3 steps:

- Create a **Model** to query through the database and return the data (as an array or object)
- Create a **Controller** to *load* and *fetch the result* from the *Model* (a method of the Model), and pass the returned data to the view
- Create a **View** and use PHP loops to echo the result out, build the HTML.

### Getting all together

Considering the above approach, you need to fetch the result from the database in your Model:

**application/models/product.php**

```php
class Product extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_product($product_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $this->db->join('versions', 'versions.product_id = products.product_id');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->first_row('array');
    }
}
```

Then fetch and pass the result within the Controller:

**application/controllers/products.php**

```php
class Products extends CI_Controller
{
    public function view($product_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('product');
        // Fetch the result from the database
        $data['product'] = $this->product->get_product($product_id);
        // Pass the result to the view
        $this->load->view('product_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Finally, use the returned data in the view, to generate the list:

**application/views/product_view.php**

```php
// Use $product to display the product.
print_r($product);
```

Comment: Anyone who downvoted this answer, consider to leave a comment in you found this irrelevant or useless

Comment: It doesn't seem to defer much from using foreach loop solution above because I have to call the above function for each product id, as using following where condition in above function: $this->db->where('username', $username); results in a null array.

Comment: @adnankamili I assumed you want to display **only** one product. in order to display the whole products, you should remove the *WHERE* clause and use `$query->result_array()` instead. And it improves the performance, you could use the CI profiler to compare the benchmarks. Here you can check the functionality of [SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join).

Comment: AFAIK *"view is passive and unaware of model"* is not true in CodeIngniter 3.1.9. If you load the model in the controller, you can use it from within the view. E.g. in the **controller** you call `$this->load->model('mymodel');` then in **view** (loaded by such controller) you can call `$this->mymodel->someMethod();`

Answer (score 2):

You should do mysql query in your model, for example products_model (don't forget to load it)

Example Query : This is just select * from products

```
public function All_Products()
{
$this->db->select('');
$result = $this->db->get('products')->result_array();
return $result;
}
```

So as I see , you are foreach guy like me, rather than using mass queries.

In your controller you could load $products my your model.

```
$products = $this->products_model->All_Products();
```

My solution is creating a new array then putting new values in it.Also you need to getVersionList function in your model.

```
$newArray = array ();
foreach ( $products as $values ) {
$version = $this->products_model->getVersionList($values['product_id']);
$tmp = array (
'product_id' => $values ['product_id'], 
'product_name' => $values ['product_name'], 
'version' => $version
);
array_push ( $newArray, $tmp );
}
```

So add your new array to $data you could have them in your view file.

```
$data ['products'] = $newArray;
```

**Sorry I didnt figure out all your queries but I think its better to teach how to catch fish than giving a fish.**

Answer (score 2):

Using the below code you can call the model's method in the view file. It's worked for me and is so simple also.

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->model_name->method_name();
```