# Model is not loading in view file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load model in my view file but problem is model is not loading and given error `Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$CoupanCatModel`

Following is my code

Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CoupanCategory extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('coupans/CoupanCatModel');
        //$this->load->model('ForeignData_model');
    }
    public function init(){
        $logoUrls = 'no-image.jpg';
        $webUrls = 'no-image.jpg';
        $mobileUrls = 'no-image.jpg';

        $this->load->library('upload');

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/coupans/category/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_size']      = 20000; 
        $config['max_width']     = 1024; 
        $config['max_height']    = 768;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('ccImage')){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());     
        }
        else{
            $data = $this->upload->data();          
            $logoUrls = $data['file_name'];
        }

        $is_init = $this->CoupanCatModel->init($logoUrls);
        if ($is_init) {
            redirect(base_url().'rech/'.ACCESS_KEY.'/coupans/coupan_category?create=success&success=New coupan category create','refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect(base_url().'rech/'.ACCESS_KEY.'/coupans/coupan_category?create=failed&error=something want wrong','refresh');
        }


    }

}
```

Model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CoupanCatModel extends CI_Model {

    public function init($logoUrls)
    {

        new_id: 

        $sc_id = 'SC'.mt_rand(1000,9999);

        if ($this->check_id($sc_id)) 
            goto new_id;

        $sc_title = (isset($_POST['coupan_cat_name']) && $_POST['coupan_cat_name'] != '') ? trim($_POST['coupan_cat_name']):'';

    $sc_logo = $logoUrls;

    //  $sc_web_image = $webUrls;
        //$sc_mobile_image = $mobileUrls;

        $active_flag =1;

        $this->db->set('oc_cat_id',$sc_id);
        $this->db->set('oc_cate_name',$sc_title);
        //$this->db->set('sc_description',$sc_description);
    //  $this->db->set('sc_logo',$sc_logo);
        $this->db->set('oc_web_image',$sc_logo);
        //$this->db->set('sc_mobile_image',$sc_mobile_image);

        $this->db->set('active_flag',$active_flag);

        $this->db->insert('tbl_oc_category');

        return true;
    }   



    public function get_data($oc_cat_id = false)
    {


        if ($oc_cat_id != false) {
            $this->db->where('oc_cat_id', $sc_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('tbl_oc_category');
            return $query->row_array();
        }
            $query = $this->db->get('tbl_oc_category');
            return $query->result_array();
    }


}
```

View i just load model like

```
<?php

$this->load->model('coupans/CoupanCatModel');                               
$scData = $this->CoupanCatModel->get_data();

echo '<pre>ddsd';
print_r($records);
die();
?>
```

But problem is model is not loading and given error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$CoupanCatModel

Filename: coupans/coupan_category.php

Line Number: 139
```

Comment: Why would you do that to MVC ?

Comment: Then how can i get model data in view , i have not idea because i am new in CI.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140379/codeigniter-calling-model-on-view

Comment: Get your data from model in controller and from controller pass your data to your view

Comment: You can change your `model name` as per codeigniter `naming convention`. you can refer this link for your information. URL : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

Comment: There is no necessary to change model name.

Comment: Nowhere in your code are you using `$this->load->view(....);` . Where are you loading your view?

Comment: if you are new to CI I would strongly suggest you read (not glance at ) the user guide that is part of your installation (in a folder called user_guide) or from the codeigniter website.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: You naming your model class and filename wrong for CI http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 1):

For your own reference, you might want to read the [Codeigniter Style Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html) for filenames etc.

The code you have provided appears to be "dubious" in the fact there is no where in your code where you are loading the alleged "view".

So based upon what you have provided, I've come up with some Demo/Debug code.

Just note that your use of calling models inside views isn't quite correct in the scheme of MVC, nor is it entirely illegal.

So I've set this up on a Linux machine where filenames etc are case sensitive.

**controllers/coupans/CoupanCategory.php**

```
class CoupanCategory extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('coupans/CoupanCatModel');
    }

    public function index() {
        echo "I am the controller ".__CLASS__;
        $this->CoupanCatModel->init();

        $this->load->view('coupans/coupan_category');
    }
}
```

**models/coupans/CoupanCatModel.php**

```
class CoupanCatModel extends CI_Model{

    public function init($logoUrls = '')
    {
        echo "<br>I am the ".__METHOD__;
    }

    public function get_data($oc_cat_id = false)
    {
        return "<br>I am the ".__METHOD__;
    }
}
```

**views/coupans/coupan_category.php**

```
<?php

$this->load->model('coupans/CoupanCatModel');
$scData = $this->CoupanCatModel->get_data();

var_dump($scData);
```

And from out of all that you should get...

```
I am the controller CoupanCategory
I am the CoupanCatModel::init
string '<br>I am the CoupanCatModel::get_data' (length=37)
```

That should give you something to help solve your issue.

Comment: @Wolfgang1983 - Why oh why did you go and change all of the case on my filenames??? While that style doesn't follow the Codeigniter Style guide, it does work as I had actually Created the Code and Fully tested it... If you want to point out the issue with filename naming, then please post it as a new answer and comments to suit.

Comment: I that was was I was taught by the CI people. The showed me the example of the first letter upper case only for class and filename

Comment: @wolfgang1983 By the way - Views do not need to be 1st letter capitalised.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 - Yes it is what you were taught... But it doesn't mean it wont work. It was interesting to prove that the naming conventions used by the OP do in fact work. It's a fine line to say - "You must do it this way or else bad things will happen". The fact the OP is loading and using models inside a view is "cringe worthy" but you can't say it won't work. Thats the thing with CI - good or bad, it will let you do things in a number of ways.

Comment: Thanks for the info Tim I plus 1 for your answer any way

Comment: @wolfgang1983 - If you are going to change things - please don't go introducing typos... like class Coupancamodel :)

Comment: I can roll it all back it if you want

Comment: @wolfgang1983 - That would be nice and I'll add a comment regarding the CI style guide for reference.

Comment: Done rolled back

Comment: @wolfgang1983 - You should see if that code works for you as an exercise :)